# Action bar not showing in custom title

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme

I have set up a custom title layout and cannot see the three bars for the action bar. I am using this app on a Samsung note 10.1 that does not have a hardware menu button. My parent is android:theme so I am not sure why the action bar is hidden. target version "16 minversion is "14"

Here is the manifest file setup with custom theme.

```
       <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo_icon" 
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
```

This is the custom_title.xml to add items.

```
   <resources>
<style name="CustomWindowTitleBackground">
    <item name="android:background">#323331</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme">

    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">45dip</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitleBackground</item>
</style>
```

This is the title.xml that makes up the custom title

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_icon"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
    android:src="@drawable/logo_icon" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Application"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="   ColorMaker Simple RGB   "
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<!-- Bluetooth info -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textbluetooth"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="BlueTooth: "
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_bt_on_off"
    android:layout_width="15dp"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/circle" />

<!-- Network  info -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textspacer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text=" | "
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textnetwork"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Network : "
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textspacer1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text=" | "
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<!-- Fade  info -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textfade_on_off"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Fade : "
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textspacer2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text=" | "
    android:textSize="20dp" />
```

Menu item

```
        @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.simple_rgb__main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.title:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Prefrences.class));
        // Activity2.this.startActivity(myIntent);

        break;

    }

    return true;
}
```

Log error

```
11-24 17:47:54.593: D/AndroidRuntime(6607): Shutting down VM
11-24 17:47:54.593: W/dalvikvm(6607): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d0f2a0)
11-24 17:47:54.601: E/AndroidRuntime(6607): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-24 17:47:54.601: E/AndroidRuntime(6607): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.simplergb/com.example.simplergb.SimpleRGB_Main}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine custom titles with other title features
11-24 17:47:54.601: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2129)
11-24 17:47:54.601: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2154)
11-24 17:47:54.601: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:146)
11-24 17:47:54.601: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1260)
11-24 17:47:54.601: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-24 17:47:54.601: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-24 17:47:54.601: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4949)
11-24 17:47:54.601: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-24 17:47:54.601: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-24 17:47:54.601: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1043)
11-24 17:47:54.601: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:810)
11-24 17:47:54.601: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-24 17:47:54.601: E/AndroidRuntime(6607): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine custom titles with other title features
11-24 17:47:54.601: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:289)
11-24 17:47:54.601: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3118)
11-24 17:47:54.601: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3358)
11-24 17:47:54.601: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:314)
11-24 17:47:54.601: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1920)
11-24 17:47:54.601: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at com.example.simplergb.SimpleRGB_Main.onCreate(SimpleRGB_Main.java:169)
11-24 17:47:54.601: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5185)
11-24 17:47:54.601: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
11-24 17:47:54.601: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2093)
11-24 17:47:54.601: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: To clarify, is the whole Action Bar missing, or just your custom styling?

Comment: The custom style is applied but the 3 dot action bar is missing. All the information in the title.xml are fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the culprit, but in

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme">
```

try replacing `android:Theme` with **`android:Theme.Holo`** (or `android:Theme.Holo.Light` or some other descendant, if you prefer).

[As the docs state](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html),

> The action bar is included in all activities that use the `Theme.Holo`
>   theme (or one of its descendants)

In my current app, that was required to get Action Bar to show up in the first place.

---

Hmm, when you mention "the 3 dot action bar", do you actually mean the Action Bar ***overflow***? See **[Adding Action Items](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems)** in the documentation. What does your menu resource file look like?

Comment: Give me an error if I try to change from android:Theme. "Error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme:Holo.Light'. There is only one item in option menu which I added to post.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I meant `android:Theme.Holo.Light` (dot, not colon). If I'm still misunderstanding the problem, consider adding a screenshot to the question :)

Comment: Now it crashes when I add .Holo or .Holo.Light.  Device is running 4.1.2. runnng on device not emulator.

Comment: Curious. What error do you get in the logs? `Theme.Holo` certainly works on my Android 4.0+ devices. Try experimenting with [Theme.DeviceDefault](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html#Theme_DeviceDefault)?

Comment: I posted log, I think the error points to this:  Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine custom titles with other title features